# Get alternate values of an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could someone tell me how to get alternate values from a range of values, through Angular js?

```
monthDataCreation(){
    var startDay =1;
    var endDay = 10;
    for (var a = startDay; a < endDay; a++) {
        var element = a;
        console.log("list values like 1,2,5,7,9... ")
    }
}
```

what I need is if I set a start value and end value and on loop it I should get alternate values.

If it start with even num 2 ends at 10 then the string of alternate value should be 2,4,6,8,10.

If it start with odd num 1 ends at 10 then the string of alternate value should be 1,3,5,7,9

Is there any angular way of solution

Comment: In place of `a++` use `a = a+2` in `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could simply change `a++` to `a+=2` to achieve the desired output. You then have to change `a < endDay` to `a <= endDay` though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `filter` method of Array

```js
var original  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var alternate = original.filter(function(val,idx) {
  if(idx%2==0)
    return val;
})
console.log(alternate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function monthDataCreation(start, end) {
    var values = []
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += 2) {
        values.push(i)
    }
    return values.join(', ')
}
```

`monthDataCreation(1, 10)` will return "1, 3, 5, 7, 9"

`monthDataCreation(2, 10)` will return "2, 4, 6, 8, 10"

Answer (score -1):

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            console.log(a[i])
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.